# MEAN Stack Error when calling two different api's routes at the same time

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mlab

Having some issues with angularjs, mongoose or MongoLab. If a make two api calls to different api route at the same time, the data won't load. So i got it working by waiting for each call to finish (with promise) before making the next call. This way for me doesn't sound good for me because if any of the call fail, then the rest of the page won't load. Is there anyway i can avoid the waiting? Here is an example of what i got right now.

AngularJS Controllers Working Code:

```
// get profiles
        HomeServices.getProfile()
            .then(function (result) {
                $scope.profiles = result.data;

                // get portfolios
                HomeServices.getPortfolios()
                    .then(function (result) {
                        $scope.portfolios = result.data;

                    }, function (error) {
                        console.log(error.statusText);
                    });

            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error.statusText);
            });
```

API's:

```
// profile api
api.get('/profiles', function (req, res) {
    // model schema
    var profile = require('../models/Profile');

    // create db connection
    var db = mongoose.createConnection(config.server.db);

    // set model
    var model = db.model('profile', profile, 'Profiles');

    // find videos
    model.find({}, function (err, data) {

        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err);
        } else {
            res.status(200).send(data);
        }

        // disconnect db
        mongoose.disconnect();
    });
});

// portfolio api
api.get('/portfolios', function (req, res) {
    // model schema
    var portfolio = require('../models/Portfolio');

    // create db connection
    var db = mongoose.createConnection(config.server.db);

    // set model
    var model = db.model('portfolio', portfolio, 'Portfolios');

    // find videos
    model.find({}, function (err, data) {

        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send(err);
        } else {
            res.status(200).send(data);
        }

        // disconnect db
        mongoose.disconnect();
    });

});
```

Here is what i want to be able to do:

```
        // get profiles
        HomeServices.getProfile()
            .then(function (result) {
                $scope.profiles = result.data;



            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error.statusText);
            });

        // get portfolios
        HomeServices.getPortfolios()
            .then(function (result) {
                $scope.portfolios = result.data;


            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error.statusText);
            });
```

Here is the error i get from MongoLab:

```
{ [MongoError: server mongolab.com:59661 sockets closed] name: 'MongoError', message: 'server db... sockets closed' }
```

Update: by removing mongoose.disconnect();  everything works as needed. But I don't want to create a connection at each endpoint.

Comment: Why are you connecting/disconnecting from the db in each endpoint? I'm not familiar with the error, but I'm guessing it comes from the fact that you're trying to establish 2 db connections at the same time.

Comment: I'm new at this meant stack thing. I removed the mongoose disconnect and now it works fine. The question now is where/how to create the database connection?

Comment: I create the db connection on app initialization. Your question has changed significantly, i suggest asking it as a new question rather than morphing this one from one to another. (hint: said question has likely already been asked and answered here on SO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the error comes from the constant create/close of the mongo connection. To sustain a single connection over multiple endpoints:

```
var Portfolio = require("../models/Portfolio")
var Profile = require("../models/Profile")
var db = mongoose.connect(config.server.db)

db.connection.once("connected", function() {

    api.get("/profiles", function(req, res) { ... });

    api.get("/portfolios", function(req, res) { ... });
});
```

You are using `createConnection()` which is used for creating connections to multiple databases. Judging by these endpoints, you probably don't need that. I'd use `connect()` instead.
I recommend reading more about connections [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html)

As an aside, I defined Portfolio and Profile at the top of the file, since they may be repeated on different endpoints.